# Why is my JavaScript object function assigning its parameter name as the key instead of the argument name?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I'm fairly new to Javascript Object. I've defined a non-destructive function to update an object like this:

```
function updateObjectWithKeyAndValue(object, key, value) {
  return Object.assign({}, object, { key: value }); 
}

let object = {a: 1};
console.log(updateObjectWithKeyAndValue(object, 'b', 2));
console.log(object);
```

I'm getting the return value of the function as `{ a: 1, key: 2 }` instead of `{ a: 1, b: 2 }`. Is there something I'm not doing right? Thanks...

Comment: What about `object[key] = value;`?

Comment: D. Pardal, because I don't want to modify this same ```object```. I only want the function to return the items in the ```object``` variable plus the new key/value pair passed as arguments to the function

Answer (score 1):

`{ key: value }` is an object with a property named “key”. To name the property according to the value in the variable `key`, use a computed property name:

```js
{ [key]: value }
```

If your JavaScript environment supports object spread, the whole thing can be written as:

```js
return { ...object, [key]: value };
```